# Minimum requirements of self-answered question

Tags: discussion, self-answer

Are there any rules (or guidelines) for a Asking and Answering your own question? What are the minimum requirements a self-answered question needs to meet, or do you treat it just like a normal question (like this one)?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: By Q&A are you referring to a site, or actually just a typical question *or* answer?

Comment: @Werner Well, lets say I want to contribute to a site by sharing some secrets about a game and so I create a Q&A style question. Is Q&A style question different from normal questions?